# table is clearly visible in command line / pgadmin but not accessible in code

Tags: node.js, postgresql

for context, I'm following a simple tutorial for creating and logging a table in node.js and Postgres. 
When I run this code:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    password: '<myPassword>',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '5432',
    databse: 'testdb',
});

client
    .connect()
    .then(() => console.log('connected sucessfully'))
    .then(() => client.query('SELECT * FROM employees'))
    .then(results => console.table(results.rows))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
    .finally(() => client.end());
```

I get this error:

```
relation "employees" does not exist
```

however, when I use psql I get this:

```
postgres-# \c testdb
You are now connected to database "testdb" as user "postgres".
testdb-# \dt
           List of relations
 Schema |   Name    | Type  |  Owner
--------+-----------+-------+----------
 public | employees | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

in pgadmin the table 'employees' is very clearly present. When I remove the request for the table I don't get any other errors, so I don't think it's a connection or syntax error. I am really at a loss and would love some help.

Comment: typo `databse: 'testdb',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I missed the typo, but I'm really happy that it was something so easy to fix.